# How to use Elixir pattern matching to check if a list's item startswith a given string(in a variable)?

Tags: elixir, pattern-matching

I am new in Elixir and I would like to collect all the items of a list that startswith a given string. If I hardcode a the string as the left side of the `<>` operator, the program works otherwise I get error `ArgumentError the left argument of <> operator inside a match should be always a literal binary as its size can't be verified.`

```
defmodule StringStartsWith do
  def search([]), do: []
  def search(["Case"<> head | tail]), do: ["Case" <> head] ++ search(tail)
  def search([_head | tail]), do: search(tail)
end

StringStartsWith.search(["CaseDown", "YoHua", "CaseUp"])
|> IO.puts()
```

I want to know how can I use a variable as the left side for the `<>` operator which will hold the value of the starting sub string. A solution with a bit of explanation will really help my case.

Cheers,
DD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error message says, a variable can't be used in this way, because it has no way to know how long the string on the left should be. Consider this example:

```elixir
foo <> bar = "foobar"
```

How does the language know how much of the string to assign to `foo`? However, this works:

```elixir
"foo" <> bar = "foobar"
```

Because it's clear that `"foo"` is a three byte string that matches the beggining of `"foobar"`.

This also works, using the [pin operator](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/pattern-matching.html#the-pin-operator):

```elixir
foo = "foo"
^foo <> bar = "foobar"
```

This works, because rather than asking the language to guess what to assign to `foo`, we are telling it to re-use the existing value. Unfortunately we can't pin a variable from another function parameter:

```elixir
def search([^foo <> bar | rest], foo) # can't do this
```

But you could still use patten matching inside the function, for example using a [comprehension](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/comprehensions.html):

```elixir
def search(list, string) do
  for ^string <> _ = word <- list, do: word
end
```

Or by using the [`Enum.filter/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#filter/2) with the [`match?/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#match?/2) function:

```elixir
def search(list, string) do
  Enum.filter(list, &match?(^string <> _, &1))
end
```

However in this case I personally would use [`String.starts_with?/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/String.html#starts_with?/2):

```elixir
def search(list, string) do
  Enum.filter(list, &String.starts_with?(&1, string))
end
```